# Open documents (pdf, doc, ppt) in application

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent

I'm developing a hybrid app thanks to cordova and after completing successfully the iOs part, Android seems more complicated for unknown reasons.

**What I'm trying to do :**

If you download a pdf, I'd like to open that file with my application called GMA. So if you click on a pdf document, the "open with" menu should enable you to choose GMA.
For the record, no application is installed on the android device except mine. I don't know if that could be a problem (e.g. an adobe pdf reader is needed anyway...)

**What I have :**

Since I'm developing on cordova, I build a plugin to add the file types to the ios plist file as well as to the androidManifest.xml file. That works and once done, here's what the xml file looks like:

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.gerermesaffaires.GererMesAffaires" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
</manifest>
```

**My problem(s) :**

1. It's not working at all.
2. I can't find a list for all mimeTypes to add audio, video, text, presentation, spreadsheet files. In ios this was rather simple and I didn't even have to specify all extensions, public.presentations enabled the feature for keynote and ppt files directly.

PS: My app is not displaying the pdf or any file, just encoding it to base64 and uploading it to my server using our API.

Comment: "It's not working at all" -- please explain, in greater detail, what your symptoms are and how you are testing your app.

Comment: I'm testing it on a galaxy tab and the symptom is simple: the app is not suggested in the open with menu !

Comment: Please edit your question and explain, **completely**, what "the app is not suggested in the open with menu" means. What is "the open with menu"? What app contains "the open with menu"? Where is the PDF? Most likely, your `<intent-filter>` needs a `<data>` element (or more than one) where you specify what schemes you support. I cannot advise you much on that, partly because your description of how you are trying to launch your app is too vague, and partly because I do not know what options are available to you in Cordova (e.g., via plugins).